# What is the sure way of presenting a view controller after app is opened in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to present a view controller (for Local Authentication like Touch ID/Passcode) each time the app is opened.

What is the sure way of achieving this?

My current approach is that I get the reference of tab bar controller and use that to present this view controller for Passcode/Touch ID.

But, it doesn't work when an alert controller (alert or action sheet) is displayed.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Apple recommends dismissing any alert views when the user presses the home button. If you dismiss them when the app is sent to the background then your solution will work.

Comment: ok, then it will be good, can you post the link to the apple document which describes the same

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-views/alerts/ at the bottom says "Allow the Home button to cancel alerts"

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps:

1) Take one empty viewController into your storyboard or xib.

2) Assign it as initalViewController. It will comes up as soon as splash screen will gone.

3) You can do Passcode/Touch ID stuff what you want to do.

4) After that you can go with your normal application flow.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: My initial view controller is a simple one, which is used to decide if the user is logged in or wants to log in or create account. After user logs in it goes to Tabbar controller.  And after that initial view controller doesn't come in to picture till you remove the app.

Comment: What do you like to do? When the user goes log out then you do you need to open initial view controller or direct login controller?

Comment: I would like to show a View Controller that will ask user to authenticate before continuing. And this should happen whenever user opens the app.

Comment: When you logout from your system, then you can init controller to rootViewController of your window. So it problem everytime when you logout.

Answer (score 0):

Use LAContext with LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics.
You can refer link to implement passcode feature.
http://www.appcoda.com/touch-id-api-ios8/

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to present this `LocalAuthentication Controller` to the `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow.rootViewController` from the AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, So when the app launches you'll always see the lock screen, after the use provided either a Touch Id or good creds, you'll clear and present tabBarController onto the window

Answer (score 0):

Set `storyboard reference id` for the `TouchId/Authentication view controller` in the `storyboard`.

Initialise the `authentication view controller` and present it when app come to foreground (`applicationDidBecomeActive(_:)`)

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "storyboardname", bundle: nil)
    let authenticationVC =  storyboard(withIdentifier: "authenticationvc reference id")
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(authenticationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
//After successful authentication dismiss the view and go with normal flow.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, it doesn't work. I get an error saying that the rootViewController is not in the hierarchy of the presenting view controller. When a modal like action sheet or alert view is shown

Answer (score 0):

Just make the authentication screen the initial view controller, then have it segue to your main landing page after authentication is complete.